# Remove SPARSE from column definition

Tags: sql-server

I have a mismatch between a development and production server where a column in a table is defined with the SPARSE clause in production but not development. As I'm not concerned about the space-saving that SPARSE provides, how safe is it to remove the "Is Sparse" value from the column definition? Any gotchas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**According to Microsoft**:

Changing a column from sparse to nonsparse or nonsparse to sparse requires changing the storage format of the column. The SQL Server Database Engine uses the following procedure to accomplish this change:

1) Adds a new column to the table in the new storage size and format.

2) For each row in the table, updates and copies the value stored in the old column to the new column.

3) Removes the old column from the table schema.

4) Rebuilds the table (if there is no clustered index) or rebuilds the clustered index to reclaim space used by the old column.

**Note**

Step 2 can fail when the size of the data in the row exceeds the maximum allowable row size. This size includes the size of the data stored in the old column and the updated data stored in the new column. This limit is 8060 bytes for tables that do not contain any sparse columns or 8018 bytes for tables that contain sparse columns. This error can occur even if all eligible columns have been pushed off-row.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns